# Initializing or populating multiple numpy arrays from h5 file groups

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have an h5 file with 5 groups, each group containing a 3D dataset.  I am looking to build a for loop that allows me to extract each group into a numpy array and assign the numpy array to an object with the group header name.  I am able to get a number of different methods to work with one group, but when I try to build a for loop that applies to code to all 5 groups, it breaks.  For example:

```
import h5py as h5
import numpy as np

f = h5.File("FFM0012.h5", "r+") #read in h5 file
print(list(f.keys())) #['FFM', 'Image'] for my dataset
FFM = f['FFM'] #Generate object with all 5 groups
print(list(FFM.keys())) #['Amp', 'Drive', 'Phase', 'Raw', 'Zsnsr'] for my dataset

Amp = FFM['Amp'] #Generate object for 1 group
Amp = np.array(Amp) #Turn into numpy array, this works.
```

Now when I try to apply the same logic with a for loop:

```
h5_keys = [] 
FFM.visit(h5_keys.append) #Create list of group names ['Amp', 'Drive', 'Phase', 'Raw', 'Zsnsr']

for h5_key in h5_keys:
    tmp = FFM[h5_key]
    h5_key = np.array(tmp)

print(Amp[30,30,30]) #To check that array is populated
```

When I run this code I get "NameError: name 'Amp' is not defined".  I've tried initializing the numpy array before the for loop with:

```
h5_keys = [] 
FFM.visit(h5_keys.append) #Create list of group names

Amp = np.array([])
for h5_key in h5_keys:
    tmp = FFM[h5_key]
    h5_key = np.array(tmp)

print(Amp[30,30,30]) #To check that array is populated
```

This produces the error message "IndexError: too many indices for array"

I've also tried generating a dictionary and creating numpy arrays from the dictionary.  That is a similar story where I can get the code to work for one h5 group, but it falls apart when I build the for loop.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: In your 2nd snippet, you never create Amp. In your 3rd one, you never assign anything to Amp. Are you used to using matlab? Unlike Matlab, variables don't 'stick around' from one run to the next. If you execute the 1st snippet of code, all those variables disappear at the end of the execution.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have jumped to using `h5py` and `numpy` before learning much of Python

```
Amp = np.array([])        # creates a numpy array with 0 elements
for h5_key in h5_keys:    # h5_key is set of a new value each iteration
    tmp = FFM[h5_key]
    h5_key = np.array(tmp)    # now you reassign h5_key

print(Amp[30,30,30])      # Amp is the original (0,) shape array
```

Try this basic python loop, paying attention to the value of `i`:

```
alist = [1,2,3]
for i in alist:
    print(i)
    i = 10
    print(i)
print(alist)       # no change to alist
```

---

`f` is the file.

```
FFM = f['FFM']
```

is a `group`

```
Amp = FFM['Amp']
```

is a dataset.  There are various ways of load the dataset into an numpy array.  I believe the `[...]` slicing is the current preferred one.  `.value` used to used but is now [deprecated](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.1.html#dataset-value-property-is-now-deprecated)  ([loading dataset](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data))

```
Amp = FFM['Amp'][...]
```

is an array.

```
alist = [FFM[key][...] for key in h5_keys]
```

should create a list of arrays from the `FFM` group.

If the shapes are compatible, you can concatenate the arrays into one array:

```
np.array(alist)
np.stack(alist)
np.concatatenate(alist, axis=0)   # or other axis
```

etc

```
adict = {key: FFM[key][...] for key in h5_keys}
```

should crate of dictionary of array keyed by dataset names.

In Python, lists and dictionaries are the ways of accumulating objects.  The `h5py` groups behave much like dictionaries.  Datasets behave much like numpy arrays, though they remain on the disk until loaded with `[...]`.

Comment: I got thrown in the deep end with a school project and I most certainly am lacking in python experience.  So, what you were getting at with the simple for-loop example is that I was doing manipulations within the for-loop, but not actually apply those manipulations to my array that I initiated outside of the loop.  

If I pursue the method that uses:

```alist = [FFM[key][...] for key in h5_keys]``` 

I get a single array with all 5 datasets.  I'd like to break the datasets apart and assign each one to a unique name to be used later in the code.  I appreciate the help kind stranger!

Comment: `alist` is a list (technically not an array) with  the 5 arrays.  I also showed how to collect those in a dictionary.  It isn't easy, nor recommended, in Python to create variables dynamically.  That is doing `Amp=FFM['Amp'][...]; Drive = ....' etc for each of the 5 keys.  In other words, don't try to assign each dataset to a different variable name.  That's not the Pythonic way to do things.  Use lists and dictionaries.

Comment: I see, so if I created the dictionary and I needed the object later in my code I would use ```dict["Amp"]```.  Just curious, is the reason this is better practice to keep the namespace uncluttered?